# Import data from SQL Server to R

Tags: sql, r, database, import

I'm trying to import data from SQL Server to R. I was given the server name, user name and password to the SQL Server database. I've installed RODBC in R. But I don't know how to write the odbcConnect search as I don't have the database on my computer and I only know the server name. What should I do in such a situation? Thanks!

Comment: Please continue your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) and you may find answer to your broad problem. Come back here with *specific* issues on earnest attempt(s) at solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical `SQL Server` connection using `DBI`+`odbc` packages :

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

conn <- DBI::dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "ServerName",
    Database = "DatabaseName",
    uid = "UserName",
    pwd = "Password",
    options(connectionObserver = NULL)
  )

data <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM ...")
```

`DBI` is [recommended by R Studio](https://db.rstudio.com/getting-started/connect-to-database/), and [faster than RODBC](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc#benchmarks). Credits @r2evans for [checking this](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/1ea2a1de11fc1f0aa391f9977766ccec).

Comment: I've been skeptical of that benchmark, since it uses `RODBCDBI`, which adds at least *some* layer to the `RODBC` query flow. I haven't tried `RODBC` in many years (currently using DBI and odbc), have you done a side-by-side comparison without `RODBCDBI`, by chance?

Comment: I started using RODBC and then switched to DBI because I found it  really faster on many occasions, but I didn't document a side by side comparison. I'll try to do this next week on some data to confirm this impression with facts.

Comment: Reporting avg of 5 repeats: **Write** (`head(nycflights13::flights[,-19],10000)`): `DBI::dbWriteTable` < 0.5sec, `RODBC::sqlSave` 80sec; **Read** (10K): `DBI::dbGetQuery` 0.06sec, `RODBC::sqlQuery` 0.10sec. I then inserted all 336K rows, then re-did the **Read** (336K): odbc 2.6sec, rodbc 3.5sec. DB is local docker (microsoft/mssql-server-linux) on win10 R-4.0.2, DBI-1.1.0, odbc-1.2.2, RODBC-1.3.17. (This justifies my use of `DBI` ... on a given weekend, I *write* 2-10M rows of data, dwarfing `nycflights13::flights`'s 336K rows.) (I only tested these two funcs, efficiencies may exist).

Comment: Just tested the 336K reads with `RODBCDBI`, mean time, 4.43sec. Not order-of-magnitude slower, but certainly a little slower on reads. I'll guess that writes are not significantly different than raw `RODBC`. I then tried `DBI::dbReadTable` versus `RODBC::sqlFetch` (raw whole-table load, not a query): odbc 2.05sec, rodbc 3.25sec, rodbcdbi 2.88sec.

Comment: @r2evans, I can ask this as a separate question, but why would there be performance differences? Wouldn't they use the same drivers and ultimately be a (presumably) low-overhead middle-man? I am especially surprised by the write differences. Also, thank you for taking the time to make those benchmarks.

Comment: For writing, it's likely because `RODBC` insert it [one row at a time](https://github.com/cran/RODBC/blob/master/R/sql.R#L378-L385), while `odbc` takes advantage of [batched rows and/or parameter-binding](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/8c095067aeff4088aec6871e17fd3f66122c217c/R/Table.R#L63-L83).

Comment: @r2evans - thank you. Yes, it would be much slower to insert one row at a time :) - that's a lot of unnecessary overhead both for R and SQL. This would be a nice PR as I like the lack of dependencies of [tag:RODBC]

Comment: Waldi, https://gist.github.com/r2evans/1ea2a1de11fc1f0aa391f9977766ccec. I wasn't surprised that `DBI`/`odbc` was faster, but shocked out how significant the difference turned out to be. I shouldn't be surprised that `RODBCDBI` didn't add (much/any?) overhead. (But I do believe it's a more complete comparison.)

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for benchmarking and sharing the code on github! I added a link to it in my answer. With such a performance difference, I now remember why I didn't hesitate to switch!

Comment: @Waldi hi I just tried your code, but it gave me error message, saying : "Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983:  28000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]?? 'stella' ?????"  stella is the user name. What does this error mean? I'm so confused.

Comment: could you please copy the exact error message you get? This will help determining the root cause of this error message : username  wrong or something else.

Comment: If the exact message contains 'Login failed for user stella', make sure with your db administrator that the user 'stella' exists and check that you didn't make a mistake on typing the password.

Comment: @Waldi Thank you for your advice. I tried again and found that I used the old password instead of the new one. (Sorry I'm so forgetful that I forgot I've changed the password after I first logged in the database.) The code is now working. Thank you very much!