# package RODBC is not available for R version 3.5.1. How can I create ODBC DSN?

Tags: r, version, rodbc

package RODBC is not available for R version 3.5.1. How can I create ODBC DSN?

Whenever I try to connect SQL server, I get an error of package unavailability.
Is there any substitute for RODBC package?

Comment: You could try installing an older version. Ensure you have devtools installed first: `install.packages("devtools")` then `devtools::install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RODBC/RODBC_1.3-16.tar.gz")` should install a previous version that is compatable with your version of R.

Comment: Perhaps try [DBI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420758/13513328)

Comment: You should update R.